# IPFS static websites deploy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, svelte, ipfs

I'm trying deploy static websites on IPFS generated by `NuxtJS` and `SapperJS`.

In both cases, I got the same errors:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Because the links in the HTML looks like this:

```
<link href="client/main.850609924.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I visit any `index.html`, all statics prompted with `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` rather than `http://127.0.0.1:8080/ipfs/<hash>`

I try to change the settings before generating a static site, but it does not lead to success.

When I deploy the same static site on `Neltify` or `AWS`, then everything works as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that a lot of static website generators assume website root to be at `/`

When you load website from IPFS [path gateway](https://docs.ipfs.io/guides/guides/addressing/#path-gateway) the root is at `/ipfs/` instead of `/`, that is why generated HTML/JS is unable to find files.

There are two ways of dealing with it:

- configure your static website generator to produce HTML with relative paths (issue for [NuxtJS](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2892))

  - this is prefered way: if your framework does not support relative paths, contribute an upstream fix, so its fixed for everyone else
- load your website from IPFS [subdomain gateway](https://docs.ipfs.io/guides/guides/addressing/#subdomain-gateway), where Origin root is at `/`

Answer (score 0):

You can try deploying the static site on to IPFS in a few clicks with terminal.co
It builds and uploads the directory to ipfs, returns a hash, and maps it to a subdomain with a txt record with the hash. any domains added afterward point to the subdomain and the txt record is updated for all future builds